# Partial derivatives at (0,0)

Tags: partial-derivative

Prove that $\dfrac{2(x^3+y^3)}{x^2+2y}$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$.

Also show that the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ at $(0,0)$ exist.

Comment: The expression is undefined at $(0,0)$, so you need to add a definition for the function at that point. In the present version, asking whether the partial derivatives exist has no sense.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

As mentioned by *Greg* the function is undefined at $(0,0)$ so you should add the value of $f$ at this point. Let's assume that $f(0,0)=0$. Prove by taking the limit in the direction $y=-\frac{x^2+x^3}{2}$ that 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$$
doesn't exist.

By the definition
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x}\quad;\quad\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}{y}$$